# react-navigation redux dispatch is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-navigation

Im getting an error in my react-native redux app using react-nativigation, I have a multi stage register page which redirects after first stage is completed.

The redirection is successful, but the following error is displayed.

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: dispatch is not a function
```

I am calling the dispatch in a promise, as below:

```
    export const registerUser = ({ email, username, password }) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_START });

  register(email, username, password)
    .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS });
        dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'RegisterDetails' }));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error', error);
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_FAIL })
  });
};
```

These are my routes

```
const AuthStack = StackNavigator({
  RegisterUser: { screen: RegisterUser },
  RegisterDetails: { screen: RegisterDetails },
  RegisterComplete: { screen: RegisterDetails },
  PasswordRecovery: {screen: PasswordRecovery}
});

const AppStack = StackNavigator({
  Landing: { screen: Landing }
});

const AppNavigator = SwitchNavigator({
  Auth: AuthStack,
  App: AppStack
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Auth',
});

export default AppNavigator;
```

This is my navigation reducer

```
import AppNavigator from '../routes';
const INITIAL_STATE = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction('RegisterUser');

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    let nextState;

    switch (action.type) {
        default:
        nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
        break;
    }
    return nextState || state;
};
```

If I click on the back button, the app crashes and I get the following error 
screen[image]

Comment: Your dispatch function is undefined.

Comment: Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Edit your post showing the entire file. For now, there is not enough information to help you.

Comment: I updated original post, hopefully that will help thanks